# Why does Bitcoin Core not let met change the label for "requested payments"?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I created a receive address, entered "fdjdsgudhsgudfhgfhdgf" without thinking about it (I was going to describe it properly later) and sent coins to it from a different wallet.

Then I later changed it to "Accurate description blabla" in the "Transactions" tab, which it allowed me to do. Then I looked in the "Receive" tab and saw that it still had the stupid gibberish label there. So I went to change the label... only to realize to my horror that there is no way to change the label there, once created... ?!

Please tell me I'm hallucinating or missing something. I'll forever be annoyed by this if I'm somehow forced to keep that "fdjdsgudhsgudfhgfhdgf" label. *Especially* as it's now renamed in the "Transactions" tab...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for may be:

In version 0.21 Open the `Windows` menu and choose `Receiving Addresses`

[image: Bitcoin core's Window menu]

In older versions you had to open the `File` menu and choose `Receiving Addresses`

[image: Bitcoin core's "File" menu]

then right-click on any unwanted label and choose `Edit`.

[image: Bitcoin Core's Address List]

Comment: No such option, but I assume that you meant "Window" instead of "File"? Either way, that strange list does not even list my label at all. Why is there a hidden separate GUI list like that anyway? That really confuses me. This sadly just made me have even more questions instead...